# Add text between two patterns in File using sed command

Tags: linux, unix, sed

I want to add Some large code between two patterns:

**File1.txt**

```
This is text to be inserted into the File.
```

**infile.txt**

```
Some Text here
First
Second
Some Text here
```

I want to add **File1.txt** content between *First* and *Second* :

Desired Output:

```
Some Text here
First
This is text to be inserted into the File.
Second
Some Text here
```

I can search using two patterns with sed command ,But I don't have idea how do I add content between them.

```
sed '/First/,/Second/!d' infile
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since `/r` stands for *reading in a file*, use:

```
sed '/First/r file1.txt' infile.txt
```

You can find some info here: [Reading in a file with the 'r' command](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-37).

Add `-i` (that is, `sed -i '/First/r file1.txt' infile.txt`) for in-place edition.

To perform this action no matter the case of the characters, use the `I` mark as suggested in [Use sed with ignore case while adding text before some pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16917665/1983854):

```
sed 's/first/last/Ig' file
```

---

As indicated in comments, the above solution is just printing a given string after a pattern, without taking into consideration the second pattern.

To do so, I'd go for an awk with a flag:

```
awk -v data="$(<patt_file)" '/First/ {f=1} /Second/ && f {print data; f=0}1' file
```

Given these files:

```
$ cat patt_file
This is text to be inserted
$ cat file
Some Text here
First
First
Second
Some Text here
First
Bar
```

Let's run the command:

```bash
$ awk -v data="$(<patt_file)" '/First/ {f=1} /Second/ && f {print data; f=0}1' file
Some Text here
First                             # <--- no line appended here
First
This is text to be inserted       # <--- line appended here
Second
Some Text here
First                             # <--- no line appended here
Bar
```

Comment: If you read the question again, @Mann is looking to insert the content between `Fist` and `Second`
Just consider the below file and what would be the command
`Some Text here`
`First`
`First`
`Second`
`Some Text here`
I am not sure the code you mentioned would satisfy the user's request.

Comment: @AlexRajKaliamoorthy well this is an edge case that apparently was not relevant to Mann, since he marked the answer as accepted. In case this was necessary, some `awk` would do the job better.

Comment: Indeed the solution is buggy, since this never replaces the text between the two lines, but keeps adding text after the first line.

Comment: @Droidzone I revisited the answer to cover that case. Thanks for the reminder!

Comment: @AlexRajKaliamoorthy I just added an `awk` variant with flags to cover this. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1):

i think you can try this

```
$ sed -n 'H;${x;s/Second.*\n/This is text to be inserted into the File\
&/;p;}' infile.txt
```

Comment: This is not a solution since you're not reading text between the two lines.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` flavor:

```
awk '/First/ { print $0; getline < "File1.txt" }1' File2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cut of bash code that I wrote to insert a pattern from patt_file. Essentially had had to delete some repetitious data using uniq then add some stuff back in. I copy the stuff I need to put back in using lineNum values, save it to past_file. Then match patMatch in the file I'm adding the stuff to.

```
   #This pulls the line number from row k, column 2 of the reduced repitious file       
   lineNum1=$(awk -v i=$k -v j=2 'FNR == i {print $j}' test.txt)    

    #This pulls the line number from row k + 1, coulmn 2 of the reduced repitious file
    lineNum2=$(awk -v i=$((k+1)) -v j=2 'FNR == i {print $j}' test.txt)

    #This pulls fields row 4, 2 and 3 column into with tab spacing (important) from reduced repitious file 
    awk -v i=$k -v j=2 -v h=3 'FNR == i {print $j"  "$h}' test.txt>closeJ.txt

    #This substitutes all of the periods (dots) for \. so that sed will match them
    patMatch=$(sed 's/\./\\./' closeJ.txt)

    #This Selects text in the full data file between lineNum1 and lineNum2 and copies it to a file 

    awk -v awkVar1=$((lineNum1 +1)) -v awkVar2=$((lineNum2 -1)) 'NR >= awkVar1   && NR <= awkVar2 { print }' nice.txt >patt_file.txt 

    #This inserts the contents of the pattern matched file into the reduced repitious file              
    #The reduced repitious file will now grow
    sed -i.bak "/$patMatch/ r "patt_file.txt"" test.txt
```