# insert a file after a specific line

Tags: regex, bash, vim, sed, awk

I want to insert some text at some particular position in a file using shell script say for example at line 3 in a file.

I have an input file:

```
input.txt
---------
Apple
Orange
Cat
Dog
```

and another sample file:

```
sample.txt
-----------
Sample data1
Sample data2
```

Now my output file should be like:

```
output.txt
----------
Apple
Orange
Sample data1
Sample data2
Cat
Dog
```

I have written a script but it can place only on beginning of the file:

```
#!/bin/bash
if grep  "Text exists..." "./input.txt"; then
echo exist
else
   echo doesNOTexist
   cat sample.txt >> output.txt
   cat input.txt >> output.txt
fi
```

Please help me how to insert lines at some specific position instead of beginning or end of the file.

I am using UNIX with bash shell.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add text between two patterns in File using sed command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16836306/add-text-between-two-patterns-in-file-using-sed-command)

Comment: what is your criteria for placing the new text there? below line 2? above "Cat"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `awk`

```
awk 'NR>2{while((getline a < "sample.txt") > 0){print a}}1' input.txt
```

#### Explaination:

- `NR` is `awk` built in variable that stores line number. When we put a condition `NR>2` the `action` that follows that condition will only execute once it is true. That is, lines for another file will only start showing up after 2nd line of your main file.
- The return value of `getline` function is 1 if line was captured and 0 if end of file was reached.
- Using `while(..)` loop along with `getline` would mean continue this loop until entire file is fetched with `getline` and `print` it.
- The `1` at the end is basically a non-zero value telling `awk` to do it's default action which is `print`.

Comment: Thanks Jaypal, can you please help me in understanding the awk command that you have used.

Comment: @chaitanya Added some explanation. Hope that helps.

Comment: I think that will insert the file for every line after the second ( NR ==3 ) would just do once

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '2rsample.txt' input.txt >output.txt
```

Comment: Thanks potong, can you please tell me how this command works?

Comment: @chaitanya this command says following line `2` read(`r`) the file `sample.txt` of the file `input.txt` and direct the output to `output.txt`

Answer (score 0):

One way using [vim](/questions/tagged/vim)

Content of `script.vim`:

```
set backup
n
normal ggyG
N
normal 3GP
saveas output.txt
qa!
```

Run it like:

```
vim -S script.vim input.txt sample.txt
```

And it will create an `output.txt` with content:

```
Apple
Orange
Sample data1
Sample data2
Cat
Dog
```