# Bash merge files wihtin two timestamps (log file)

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

I have two files.

test.log

```
sadfsdfdasfasdf 

2015-07-07 11:23:33,006 DEBUG : Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor@2798240a

    name="Demo SG, St. Gallen/*"
    domicile="Ottikon"
    domicile="Zürich"
    domicile="Uster"
    name="Luca Gubler"

2015-07-07 15:00:33,008 DEBUG : Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.

asdfasdfasdfdsgdg
adgasdasdgsdgasdsdg

2015-07-07 16:00:33,008 DEBUG : Invoking handleMessage on interceptor and replace.txt
```

and replace.txt

```
2015-07-07 11:23:33,006 DEBUG : Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor@2798240a
name="name1"
domicile="domicile1"
domicile="domicile2"
domicile="domicile3"
name="name2"
2015-07-07 15:00:33,008 DEBUG : Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.
```

So my question is: How can i merge my replace.txt file in my test.log file, so that it only replaces the part between the two timestamps in the replace.txt file? I am working with bash.

Thanks

Comment: does replace.txt only have the one segment/range of timestamps ( ifso why not just use a texteditor - they're quite cheap ;)

Comment: WOW, I didn't know you can use a texteditor XD. But I need this logic for my script. The script loops over all log files in a directory. and i want to pass a timestamp as an argument, so that the script only replaces from 09:00 to 10:00 for example

Comment: so is it 1. multiple test.log files which you run against the one replace.txt, 2. multilple replace.txt for each test.log file or 3. something completely different

Comment: I don't think this is possible without writing your own program, regular expressions cannot understand number/time intervals (e.g. from 09:00 to 10:00)-

Comment: Take a look over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16836306/add-text-between-two-patterns-in-file-using-sed-command) on how to add text lines between two patterns using e.g. `sed`

Comment: my interpretation is the timestamp lines match exactly ( as delimeters ) the test.log file ( so no regex handling for that.. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for my script in another stack overflow post

```
sed -i -ne '/2015-07-07 11:23:33,006/ {p; r replaced_time_search.txt' -e ':a; n; /2015-07-07 15:00:33,008/ {p; b}; ba}; p' logs/new_test.log
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

2 ways:

bash:

```
mapfile -t markers < <(sed -n '1p; $p' replace.txt)
print=true
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ $line == "${markers[0]}" ]]; then
        print=false
        cat replace.txt
    fi
    $print && echo "$line"
    [[ $line == "${markers[1]}" ]] && print=true
done < test.log
```

GNU awk

```
gawk '
    NR==1 {start = $0; next} 
    NR==FNR {rep[++n] = $0; next} 
    ENDFILE {stop = $0} 
    $0 == start { 
        print; 
        while ($0 != stop) getline
        for (i=1; i<n; i++) print rep[i]
    }
    {print}
' replace.txt test.log
```